# Acceleo file tags

Tags: java, file, tags, acceleo

I'm new to Acceleo and I'm trying to figure out some things about the file tags I can use.
The format I see most commonly is something like that:

```
[file (someElement.anotherElement.concat('SomeText.java'), false, 'UTF-8')]
```

1st Question: How can I write some text first and then the text from some element? e.g. Create a file named "SomeTextElement1.java". Where Element1 is a property(or something) from an .ecore file)

2nd Question: How can I take values from 2 different elements?
e.g. Create a file named "Element1-Element2.java". Where Element1 and Element2 taken from an .ecore file.

and 3rd Question: How can I put a file statement inside an [if] statement???
e.g.

```
[if (condition) /]
[file (Element1.concat('.java'),false, 'UTF-8')]
[else if (condition)]
[file (Element1.concat('.java'),false, 'UTF-8')]
[if/]
```

I get an error saying file tag is not terminated. But i don't want to terminate it inside the if statement because then i would have to write the same code twice... all i want is to change the filename if a condition is true.. is that possible or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally don't want to have external "if"s for this. The file name itself is an expression, not a simple string, so you can achieve what you're trying to get with the following:

```
[file (if (condition) then 'somename.java' else 'someothername.java' endif, false, 'UTF-8')]
```

Note that in this case, the "if" structure you'll be using is the OCL "if", so you have to properly use the "if then else endif" structure. if you want multiple conditions, this will then become

```
if (condition) then 'somename' else
    if (otherCondition) then 'someothername' else 'yetanothername' endif
endif
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Actually this is the answer to my 3rd Question. The exact answer I was looking for. Plus I found the answer to my first 2 question by myself. I 'm just posting it here for anyone else who may read this:

1st question: Basically it was easy... just write [file ("someText" + Element1.concat(.java), (...), (...) ) ]

and 2nd question: The same logic [file (element1+element2+"someText.java,(...),(...) ) ]

thanks again... appreciate it...

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate two different file for a same type on a condition, you have multiple options:

You can do as proposed by @Kellindil in the `[file ()]` tag

You can also use your solution but by ending the `[/file]` tag in the `[if..]` like this:

```
[if (condition)]
[file ('name1', ...)]
...
[/file]
[elseif (condition)]
[file ('name2', ...)]
...
[/file]
[/if]
```

Finally, you can also use a guard on the template that owns the code:

```
[template public generate_stuff(p : your_type) ? (condition1)]
[file ('name1' ....)]
...
[/file]
[/template]

[comment Yep, the template name is exactly the same, only the condition change/]
[template public generate_stuff(p: your_type) ? (condition2)]
[file ('name2' ....)]
...
[/file]
[/template]
```

This later solution is probably the best as you can clearly 'cut' your code and write a dedicated implementation regarding the condition.

(you could also use a solution that mixes the `if` solutions with multiple templates)

EDIT>

The last solution can produce the same code, no issues about that

```
[template public generate_stuff(p : your_type) ? (condition1)]
[file ('name1' ....)]
[p.body_generation()/]
[/file]
[/template]

[comment Yep, the template name is exactly the same, only the condition change/]
[template public generate_stuff(p: your_type) ? (condition2)]
[file ('name2' ....)]
[p.body_generation()/]
[/file]
[/template]

[template public body_generation(p: your_type)]
...
[/template]
```

Acceleo is a really verbose language, trying to put everything on a single statement is often not a great idea for readability.

Comment: I don't know if I didn't make myself understood or if I don't understand your answer, but I think I wanted the exact oposite of what you posted... I don't want to write a different code if the condition is true or false... I wanted to write the exact same code I just wanted it to have a different file name... anyway thanks for the answer :)

Comment: This is not an issue, the last solution is perfectly relevant and better (it uses guards and is easier to read), if you need the same code, then you write a new template and call it. I edit my answer to show you how.